# Spring Boot and AJAX for loading page when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Hey :)   I have some problems with Spring Boot and AJAX. At the moment i have buttons , that i have to click to go to another page (next , previous). I want to substitute that with ajax request to load my page when scrolling down . I am new in Spring framework , could someone explain to me the way to implement it  ?

```
@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    @Autowired
    private AirUserService service;

    @Autowired
    private OfferService offerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/homepage"} , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView modelAndView , @RequestParam(name="p" , defaultValue="1")  int pageNumber) {

        Page<Offer> page =  offerService.getPage(pageNumber);

        modelAndView.getModel().put("offerpage", page);
        modelAndView.setViewName("app.homepage");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: It seems more related with your client side technology rater than with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

In the client site you need a `script` which will fire `ajax` call as soon as page is scrolled down to the bottom. This ajax call will give you the further data.

Below is the jQuery script

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
       alert("bottom!");
       // getData();
   }
});
```

It will be better if you have any `template` based implementation in your page.